# Restricting redirects using RewriteCond on a drupal multisite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a drupal multisite, therefore, my redirects get added to the same htaccess. The problem is my `RewriteCond` are not working correctly.

My `RewriteRule` for `example1.com` is also working on `example2.com` which I do not want. These redirects are site specific. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
# START redirects of example1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/new-equipment/marine-engines$ /products/new/marine [R=301,L]
# END redirects of example1.com

# START redirects of example2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.example2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/new/machines/405/(.*) /products/new [R=301,L]
# END redirects of example2.com
```

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: Dang, I was afraid of that response lol. I'd also like to note that redirects on `example2.com` are working on `example1.com` as well.

Comment: I figured it out..didn't realize rewritecond's only apply to just the following rule. My code above was a trimmed version so yep what I posted was correct